# Xcode Generic iOS Device but no Emulators

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I generated a build on an app for the App Store awhile back. Now I am making some changes but when I try to Run the app in Xcode v7.3.1 I see an alert saying "A build only device cannot be used to run this target. No supported iOS devices are available. Connect a device to run your application or choose a simulated device as the destination."

I can build the app and run it on my iPhone but my emulators have disappeared from the dropdown list of run targets.

I tried cleaning the build and setting Build Settings > iOS Deployment Target to 7.1 as suggested by others but to no avail.

How can I can get my emulators back in the list of run targets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode has been buggy lately, try to close out Xcode and re-run the project, If that doesn't work make sure your root folder which holds your project contains your project name an make sure the project names are exactly the same, this happened to me yesterday!